# Docker Compose - can I set priority of multiple environment files?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a profile in my Compose file like:

```
  web_prod_db:
    <<: *web
    command: etc. etc.
    env_file:
      - .env
      - .env.prod-db
    profiles:
      - myprofile
```

I want the values in `.env.prod-db` to override the (same-named) variables in `.env`, but this doesn't seem to happen - even if I swap the order that the files are specified so `.env.prod-db` is specified first.

Is there anything I can do here to ensure the overrides happen as desired?

Answer (score 2):

As stated [here](https://www.shellhacks.com/docker-compose-set-environment-variables/):

> Environment Files Order: The environment files in the Docker Compose are processed from the top down. For example, for the same variable specified in the file ./common.env and assigned a different value in the file ./apps/db.env, the value from ./apps/db.env stands as this file is listed below (after) the ./common.env file.

So the variable defined for a second time in `.env.prod-db` takes president over `.env`

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I was definitely finding, regardless of the order I specified the files (I tried both), that one was taking precedence and overwriting variables. Perhaps I'll revisit this at some point. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To override values, you can use this approach: https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/

You can create your main docker-compose.yml file, and others dockerfiles that will override values that you desired. As an example:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
web:
  image: example/my_web_app:latest
  depends_on:
    - db
    - cache

db:
  image: postgres:latest

cache:
  image: redis:latest
```

**docker-compose.prod.yml**

```
web:
  ports:
    - 80:80
  environment:
    PRODUCTION: 'true'

cache:
  environment:
    TTL: '500'
```

And run the command:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d
```

That will run your containers and will override/merge the values from  **docker-compose.yml** with the values defined in **docker-compose.prod.yml**

Hope this can be usefull

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the question specifically of multiple `env_file:`.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and i figured out that the `.env` is always loaded last, even if you put it into the `env_file` list.

The best you can do is to not use a file named `.env`.
If you rename it with `.env.default` for instance, it will works as you expect.

Avoid the var composition too (eg. `DB=$DBHOST:$DBPORT`). It not works as expected.Do it in docker-compose.yml files if you want but dont do it in env files.